# How to add custom class control in xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xaml

I have extended properties of a button control and saved using xml and xaml. Now when I read it back, I get an error:

> The tag 'ClasA' does not exist in XML namespace.

I have done my extending like this

```
ClassA : Button
{
  string a;
}

Main()
{
 Button b1= new ClassA();
}
//code to read

     StringReader Reader = new StringReader(inputfile);
     XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(Reader);

                    Button tempbutton =(Button)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
// end of code
```

How to read back and create a Button back?

Comment: you probably have to add your namespace as an xmlns in the xaml file but not sure as you haven't shared the code where the error happens. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747086(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Dhunt I have edited with the read code plz tell what changes to make . I read your link but its complicated can you tell as a code example ?

Comment: Windows Forms UI is not intended to be saved in/loaded from XML, and what to say about XAML. You are using hacks and expect it to work? If you need XAML, use WPF then.